# Is it possible to use java code in a python program?

Tags: java, python, import, python-import

So i am curious if it is possible to use a java function in a python program?

Lets say i have a python script that has unsorted list

for example:

//main.py

```
pylist = ['4', '2', '5', '1', '3']

#call java selection sort here

#then print sorted list
for x in pylist:
    print(x)
```

and I want to sort the list from the python script using an algorithm from a java class. Is this possible at all?
Is it as simple as importing the java package into the python script and then use a statement like: "selectionsort(pylist)" ?

selection sort comes from here:

//sort.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class sortexample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] ar =  {4, 2, 5, 1, 3};
        printarray(ar);
        System.out.printf("%n");
        Arrays.sort(ar);
        printarray(ar);
    }

    public static void printarray(int[] array)
    {
        for(int a: array)
        {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }


    public static int[] selectionsort(int[] arr)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
                if(arr[j] < arr[index])
                { 
                    index = j;
                }

            int smallerNumber = arr[index];  
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: The standard `sort` and `sorted()` methods are very polished C based implementations of Timsort. So aside from the case where you really need to implement you own sorting, you should use them.

Comment: Sure! **If** you use [jython](http://www.jython.org/).

Comment: I don't think that will work. Jython: Python for the Java Platform

Comment: @GlenPierce [How to use Java from Jython?](http://www.jython.org/faq1.html)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That is Python in Java, not Java in Python, right?

Comment: @GlenPierce You can invoke Java from Python (in Jython). You still have to compile the Java with javac.

Answer (score 1):

No. But you could try to rewrite the Java code into Python code and use that instead. This is because Java runs on the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) and requires compilation before it can be run whereas Python is a scripting language that does not require any compilation. The two languages are not compatible with each other in any setting with which I am familiar.

The Python interpreter expects Python and can't understand Java syntax.

There are some languages that can be used together in some very specific circumstances. For example, I can write JavaScript in Java in the GWT framework if I write it as JSNI.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Jython](http://www.jython.org/), which is compliant with CPython 2.7 and gives you access to java classes.

Check [here](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/03/27/jython.html) for usage examples, but I *imagine* you would need something like:

```
>>> from sort import sortexample
>>> sample = [2,7,6,5,4,3,1]
>>> sortexample.selectionsort(sample)
```

That might not convert nicely with the java types.

Or you could [implement selection sort](https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheSelectionSort.html) in python.

Answer (score 0):

More for completeness: of course you can use java code within python scripts.

You simply compile the Java code, then you make a subprocess call to trigger a JVM run.

But the closest thing to a reasonable solution is jython. Although that implies that you technically run a JVM that is python enabled.